# ZAP and Tamper Data is not getting any POST requests

Tags: owasp, zap, webgoat

I just started learning the OWASP ZAP Proxy using Webgoat. I am running these on my Mac.

I have configured Zap to listen to my Firefox, but I'm only able to send HTTP GET requests, there are no POST requests showing up.

I also tried to use the Firefox add-on Tamper Data, and I also get no POST results.

When I tried the same task on my Windows desktop, it works fine.

[image: Zap with no Post showing]

Comment: On the top left pane, it appears there's a request marked "POST". Is that an old request or the one you're looking for?

Comment: I believe this may be due to the form on each environment. On your Mac machine, your vulnerable application may only be accepting `GET` requests, where on Windows, your application is only accepting `POST` requests. For example: `<form action="hack-me.php" method="get">` vs. `<form action="hack-me.php" method="post">`. See if you can change the vulnerable value from `GET` to `POST`, and let us know. Otherwise, you may be missing an option somewhere.

Comment: @Ohnana It is the post request I got when I login to webgoat, and its the only post I get.

Comment: Maybe you're not making any more post requests then?